# Не работает текстовая/видео реклама admob

Tags: android, admob

Обычный баннер работает, а контекстовая реклама и видео не работает(межстраничное объявление). Вообще пустое место ничего вообще не показывает.

main_activity

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

main.xml

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                        android:id="@+id/adView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        ads:adSize="BANNER"
                        ads:adUnitId="мой код">                 // мой код 
                    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: если ответ решил вашу проблему то его можно отметить "верным", нажав галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Видео и межстраничная реклама могут работать только в больших `View`. У вас же баннер маленький (`ads:adSize="BANNER"`) и они там не поместятся. Засим вам надо или как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25169122/3212712) создать отдельную `AdView` для этих типов реклам или вообще не создавать для них отдельного `View`, а доверить их создание самому `adMob`-у, как показано в официальной документации по [Interstitial Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)

Также проверьте, что эти типы рекламм включены в вашем аккаунте как показано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26595972/3212712)

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ, сейчас буду пробывать... типы рекламы включены...

Comment: помогите пожалуйста написать код непонимаю((

Comment: @Андрей, предлагаете мне скопировать код с доков в ответ?..

Comment: а какой написать код что-бы при в каждом входе в приложение реклама автоматически отображалась?

Comment: @Андрей, это уже другой вопрос. Вы можете его задать отдельно. Звучать он должен так: `отследить запуск приложения`. Решить можно по разному. Напрмер проверять `savedInstanceState==null` (это агрумент в `onCreate`) и если `true`, то загружать рекламу: `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder() .build();   mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);`

Comment: я сейчас создам другой вопрос напишите пожалуйста весь код